# ListView items do not appear when added

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to insert some items to my ListCtrl. This is my Code. I can't seem to get errors in the program. Unfortunately, not All items show in List, I can't know why it is. Please help me.

```
    LVITEM lItem;

    lItem.mask=LVIF_TEXT;
    lItem.iItem = 1 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem=0;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(L"");
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.InsertItem( 1 + (nColNum-1 ) * 3 , lItem.pszText);

    WCHAR szzText[MAX_PATH];

    lItem.iItem = 1 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 1;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szGameName);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText(1 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 1 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.mask=LVIF_TEXT;
    lItem.iItem = 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szGameTime);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.InsertItem(2 + + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 1;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szA_Team);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 1 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 2;
    if (m_arData[nColNum - 1].bFT_HDP)
    {
        swprintf(szzText , L"%s   %s" , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_HDP , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_A_HDP);
        lItem.pszText = W2T(szzText);
    }
    else
        lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_A_HDP);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 2 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 3;
    swprintf(szzText , L"%s   %s" , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_UO , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_A_UO);
    lItem.pszText=W2T(szzText);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 3 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 4;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_S_Odd);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 4 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 5;
    if (m_arData[nColNum - 1].bHT_HDP)
    {
        swprintf(szzText , L"%s   %s" , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_HDP , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_A_HDP);
        lItem.pszText=W2T(szzText);
    }
    else
        lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_A_HDP);      
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 5 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 6;
    swprintf(szzText , L"%s   %s" , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_UO , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_A_UO);
    lItem.pszText=W2T(szzText);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 6 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 7;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_S_Odd);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 2 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 7 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.pszText = W2T(L" ");
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.InsertItem( 3 + (nColNum-1 ) * 3 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 1;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szB_Team);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 1 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 2;
    if (!m_arData[nColNum - 1].bFT_HDP)
    {
        swprintf(szzText , L"%s   %s" , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_HDP , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_B_HDP);
        lItem.pszText=W2T(szzText);
    }
    else
        lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_A_HDP);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 2 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 3;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_B_UO);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 3 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 4;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szFT_D_Odd);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 4 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 5;
    if (!m_arData[nColNum - 1].bHT_HDP)
    {
        swprintf(szzText , L"%s   %s" , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_HDP , m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_B_HDP);
        lItem.pszText=W2T(szzText);
    }
    else
        lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_B_HDP);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 5 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 6;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_B_UO);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 6 , lItem.pszText);

    lItem.iItem = 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;
    lItem.iSubItem = 7;
    lItem.pszText = W2T(m_arData[nColNum - 1].szHT_D_Odd);
    pDlgSportNews->m_List.SetItemText( 3 + (nColNum - 1) * 3 , 7 , lItem.pszText);

    pDlgSportNews->m_List.UpdateData();

    UpdateData(FALSE);
```

Comment: *"There's no error in my code. Unfortunately, not All items show in List*" - Seems like an unreasonable assumption.  Also, loops are your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly going out on a limb here, but:

`lItem.iItem = 1 + (nColNum - 1) * 3;`

Why are you calculating the item number this way? This could likely be a reason not all of your items are being added.

Boilerplate for adding an item to a CListCtrl:

```
// First item  (first row)
VITEM item;
item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
item.pszText = "Column Text";
item.iItem = 0;      // Item number
item.iSubItem = 0;         // Sub item number (column number)
m_CListCtrl.InsertItem(&item);

// Second item (second row)
//...
item.iItem = 1;
//...
```

As somebody suggested, you should use a loop.

Comment: Well , The Count of Row is very big, so I can't add item one by one.

Comment: items were shown on column 1 , and the other columns items were not show.